# MongoDB failed (result: core-dump)?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I'm attempting to setup MongoDB on Ubuntu 20.04.02 LTS by following the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#install-mongodb-community-edition). I have ensured this is a fresh install. However an error persists when I verify if the MongoDB install started succesfully by typing in:

> sudo systemctl status mongod

> ● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor prese>
> Active: **failed (Result: core-dump)** since Wed 2021-08-11 12:59:20 UTC; 49s >
> Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
> Process: 3190 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=dum>    Main PID: 3190 (code=dumped, signal=ILL)
>
> Aug 11 12:59:19 discorddomagoj systemd[1](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#install-mongodb-community-edition): Started MongoDB Database
> Server. Aug 11 12:59:20 discorddomagoj systemd[1](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#install-mongodb-community-edition): mongod.service:
> Main process exited,> Aug 11 12:59:20 discorddomagoj systemd[1](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#install-mongodb-community-edition):
> mongod.service: Failed with result '>

Picture of problem for clarity:
[image: picture of problem]

Comment: Ve you enough  memory for run mongo? U can see it with df -h command on Linux

Answer (score 28, accepted):

1.Stop the `mongod` process by issuing the following command:-

```
    sudo service mongod stop
```

2.Remove any MongoDB packages that you had previously installed:-

```
    sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
```

3.Remove MongoDB databases and log files:-

```
    sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb
    sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb
```

4.Then reinstall mangodb 4.4.8

5.Import the public key used by the package management system:-

```
    wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

6.The following instruction is for Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal):-

```
    echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list
```

7.Update Apt

```
    sudo apt-get update
```

8.Install mongodb

```
    sudo apt-get install mongodb-org=4.4.8 mongodb-org-server=4.4.8 mongodb-org-shell=4.4.8 mongodb-org-mongos=4.4.8 mongodb-org-tools=4.4.8
```

9.Use `mongod --version` to check its succesfully installed

10.If u encounter any error while using `mongod`

```
    sudo mkdir /data
    cd /data
    sudo mkdir db
    sudo pkill -f mongod
```

11.Then use sudo `mongod` command.

Comment: still getting (code=exited, status=14) error

Comment: In the end I also needed to chown the /data/db dir:
`sudo chown $USER /data/db`

Comment: `mongod --version` gives `Illegal instruction (core dumped)`

Comment: Downgraded to 4.4.18, because cpu does not has AVX instructions.

Comment: Same error with 6.x version. Downgraded to 4.4 - everything is fine

Comment: and here is where to get openssl 1.11
https://gist.github.com/joulgs/c8a85bb462f48ffc2044dd878ecaa786

Answer (score 10):

This error show CPU incompatibly with mongodb. if use proxmox set cpu mode to "HOST".

Comment: This was the correct answer for me. The problem with the Proxmox default VM CPU type kvm64 is that it does not support AVX instructions which are needed by mongodb v5+. Further information: https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/mongo-db-5-0-not-install.95857/#post-440005

Answer (score 5):

A possible reason for the dump is a change in the [microarchitecture requirements](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/5.0/#minimum-microarchitecture) of MongoDB introduced with version 5.0. This causes this exact issue on a Raspberry Pi for instance (see: [MongoDB Forum](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/core-dump-on-mongodb-5-0-on-rpi-4/115291/14)).

This issue might be mitigated by building from source as described in the forum post. I haven't tried this though personally. Installing versions prior to 5.0 (as described by Abdul Wahhab) will solve the problem as well.

**Update October 2023:** You can get unofficial binaries from this [Github Repository](https://github.com/themattman/mongodb-raspberrypi-binaries). A member of the MongoDB team is providing them.

Answer (score 3):

I have same issue when installing `mongodb` on virtual machine with `proxmox`.
Changing processor from `kvm` to host or sandybridge(my actual pc) solved this problem. [Reference link](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/mongo-db-5-0-not-install.95857/)

Comment: I think changing the CPU type to anything but KVM or QEMU will fix the issue. Seems that the mongo daemon doesnt like virtual CPU's. Changing mine from KVM to EPYC fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is an addition to @AbdulWahhab 's answer. I have recently seen many questions of same type: 'can't start mongodb@5.0.x server on ubuntu@20.0.4'. Having faced this issue myself, I found installing mongodb@4.4.8 version only way out. In addition consider that `sudo apt-get update` updates all packages including mongodb. Newer version of mongodb gets installed and server does not work anymore(as of 10th december 2021). To prevent unintended upgrades, you can pin the package at the currently installed version:

```
echo "mongodb-org hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
echo "mongodb-org-database hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
echo "mongodb-org-server hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
echo "mongodb-org-shell hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
echo "mongodb-org-mongos hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
echo "mongodb-org-tools hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

Answer (score 1):

stop the db

```
sudo service mongod stop
```

uninstall it:

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
```

Import the public key used by the package management system

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-5.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Create a list file for MongoDB.

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-5.0.list
```

Reload local package database

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**Install a specific release** of the MongoDB packages(this was the reason I had that similar error for not specifying the package)

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=5.0.7 mongodb-org-database=5.0.7 mongodb-org-server=5.0.7 mongodb-org-shell=5.0.7 mongodb-org-mongos=5.0.7 mongodb-org-tools=5.0.7
```

lastly, on one tab of the terminal run:

```
sudo mongod
```

on another open the db:

```
mongo
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have tried all of the above solutions, and still can't help, please try to reboot the VM.

I am using 18.04 and initially installed 6.0 mongoDB and it just showed the core-dump error after issuing "sudo systemctl status mongod".

After doing some research, I tried to uninstall the 6.0 and then re-install 4.4, it still couldn't help.
Then I tried to re-install 4.2, it still couldn't help.

Finally, I tried to reboot the VM, then it works..

Answer (score 1):

For MongoDB 5.0+

If you are running on VirtualBox with a Windows host, disable Hyper-V. The issue is a lack of AVX support and to get it you need to disable Hyper-V and be using VirtualBox 5.03 or later.

Using CMD as Administrator

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
DISM /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V
```

Then hard shutdown and restart the host. After that, starting the guest from cold boot should work.

```
sudo systemctl start mongodb
sudo systemctl status mongodb
```

Source: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=99390

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 22.10 and MongoDB 6.0.
I solved it by put it AVX to AUTO in BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

I was going through this exact same problem bro excerpt I'm on 22.04 LTS (long-term support) so this answer might be for someone with similar problem:

**22.04 LTS ("Jammy") (Starting in MongoDB 6.0.4)**

1. **From a terminal, install gnupg and curl like so**

   sudo apt-get install gnupg curl
2. **Import the MongoDB public GPG Key from [here](https://pgp.mongodb.com/server-6.0.asc?_ga=2.35752288.1365499207.1689269810-815435998.1689269800)**

   curl -fsSL https://pgp.mongodb.com/server-6.0.asc | 
   sudo gpg -o /usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-6.0.gpg 
   --dearmor
3. **Create the list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list**

   echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-6.0.gpg ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list
4. **Reload the local package database**

```
sudo apt-get update
```

5. **You can install either the latest stable version of MongoDB or a specific version of MongoDB.**

   sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org

*This worked for me, full source is at [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#install-mongodb-community-edition)*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my application than I've found checking following link, my CPU version wasn't supported in newest version of MongoDB Server. Try to check also it. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/administration/production-notes/#platform-support-matrix

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened on my end when installing the mongodb current 7.00 version on ubuntu 22.04 using virtual box.
Issue Tittle as "mongodb illegal instruction (core dumped)".
I have tried many ways. But the problem was not resloved at all.
And finally i find out the solution.

Solution:

1. Just Uninstall the virtual box and then download and install the vmware.
2. Now install the ubuntu 22.04 inside your vmware machine
3. Then install the mongodb 7.0v

Answer (score -3):

Just for future help in case of someone else need help.

check if you have the java runtime environment (JRE), if not then install it:

`sudo apt install default-jre`

That' s all =)