# Failed to start Mongod 6.0 in virtualbox machine with ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I installed mongodb with the follow instructions:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#install-mongodb-community-edition

When I execute the command:

```
sudo systemctl start mongod
```

Apparently works correctly, but when I execute this command:

```
sudo systemctl status mongod
```

I have this error:

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Mon 2023-01-02 15:14:01 -05; 1s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 2339 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=dumped, signal=ILL)
   Main PID: 2339 (code=dumped, signal=ILL)

ene 02 15:14:01 luis-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
ene 02 15:14:01 luis-VirtualBox systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=4/ILL
ene 02 15:14:01 luis-VirtualBox systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
```

I already tried uninstalling and reinstalling but I still get the same error https://stackoverflow.com/a/74258980/15311842, do you know what it is?

Comment: Did you check the mongod logfile?

Comment: There are no logs.

Comment: Hard to believe. It is configured in `/etc/mongod.conf`, usually `/var/log/mongodb.mongod.log`. Try manual start: `/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`

Answer (score 1):

`status=4/ILL` indicates the process died because it attempted to execute an illegal instruction.  See https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/ccompiler/doc700/html/lr1/z2005346.htm

Modern MongoDB version require the [Advanced Vector Extensions(AVX)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions) instructions to be available.  (See that link for a list of processors which provide those)

A common cause is the machine is not using a processor which provides AVX, but it can also occur in VMs running on Windows if hyper-v is running.

Comment: I'm using a virtualbox machine with Ubuntu 20.04 from Windows 11 with a processor 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-11260H @ 2.60GHz   2.61 GHz. Would I have a problem with AVX? Should any configuration be done in VIRTUALBOX or in Windows?

Comment: Check the virtualbox site for details about AVX, there are several threads in the forum about that.